# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: php, setcookie

Can anyone help with this? i need to get this working ASAP

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/XXXXXXXXXXXX/public_html/advert5.html:445) in /home/XXXXXXXXX/public_html/advert5.html on line 692

```
 header ('Refresh: 2; url=dashboard.html'); 
    echo"</center>";
    }
    setcookie("user",$myid,time()+10000);
    mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php
for the ultimate answer on why you get "headers already sent"

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are actually set on the browser. Since you have used header function before settings cookie you get this error / warning message

Comment: i have cookies enabled on my browser?

Comment: Did you check the following page, this has brief explaination of why you should not use header, cookie related function after you print / echo / output anything on your script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php